# Watch for changes to session storage without $interval

Tags: angularjs

I am building an app in which I save data in one controller to session storage, and in my other controllers I use `$interval` to constantly watch the `sessionStorage` to check for changes like so.

```
    $interval(function(){
      vm.myData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('patient'));
    }, 300)
```

I feel like this is not a good way to keep watching, because, for example, if I want to allow a user to edit some of the data in vm.myData, they cant, as the variable keeps updating itself.

Is there a way to simply watch the sessionStorage object to see if `'patient'` has changed? I tried to use the `$watch` function, but i don't think I quite understand how it works.

Comment: not sure if it'll work but why not use $watch and assign the session storage to the rootScope var.

Comment: Why don't you fire an event and listen to it, instead of watching the session storage constantly. It would be a big performance boost for your app as well.

Comment: Considering that there is only one copy of application, sessionStorage read/write operations can be managed by service getters/setters. In this case RxJS observables are beneficial. Btw, polling with $interval is a terrible thing, it causes a digest on each interval.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the controller `$doCheck` Life-Cycle Hook:

```
this.$doCheck = function () {
    var previousValue;
    var currentValue;
    previousValue = currentValue;
    currentValue = sessionStorage.getItem('patient'));
    if (currentValue !== previousValue) {
       console.log("patient changed");
    };
};
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference -- Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks).